# React native admob installing

Tags: react-native

Hi I'm trying to show ads in my sample app.I got verified admob and firebase account. My steps:

Installing admob

```
npm i -S react-native-admob@next
```

Linking

```
react-native link react-native-admob
```

android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.sample">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
//it should be here ***
//I added this line
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-6758XXXX6788401~XXXXXXXXX"/>
    </application>

//I added this line
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-6758XXXX6788401~XXXXXXXXX"/>

</manifest>
```

App.js

```
import {AdMobBanner} from 'react-native-admob';

const Example = () => {


  return (

    <ImageBackground source={require('./assets/bg.jpg')} style={styles.ImageBg}>
      <StatusBar hidden={true} />

      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', }}>
      <AdMobBanner
          adSize="largeBanner"
          adUnitID="ca-app-pub-67584xxx6788401/19xxx7"
          testDeviceID="CF583E54-34C6-453C-80FC-493D2468A51E" //I don't know this
          didFailToReceiveAdWithError={onFailToRecieveAd}
        />
....
```

it gived error in *node_modules/react-native-admob* in three java files.

Error: "*react-native-admob:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED* " I solved it with

```
import android.support.annotation.Nullable
```

to

```
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
```

now it's not giving error but not working too.It gives Unfortunately app has stopped

SOLUTION.
I fixed now it's because of the metadata. Now it shows test ads. How can I show real ads in react native.
Thank you

Comment: hello , try to share the android logcat crash. Also I think instead of manually change that import just in postinstall execute npx jetify that fix all android 10 issues

Comment: I'm just trying to make it for Android and I think pod for IOS,. I don't have any Apple machine.Is this code will show real ads